# Print list of lists in matrix format

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
[[15 16 18 19 12 11],[13 19 23 21 16 12],[12 15 17 19 20 10],[10 14 16 13 9  6]]
```

**The length of each list in the list is the same**.
I want to print out as rows and columns such as:

```
15 16 18 19 12 11

13 19 23 21 16 12

12 15 17 19 20 10

10 14 16 13  9  6
```

I know I can do it by using

```
lst = (' '.join(map(str,lst))),
```

But I want every integer to indent at the same level like the `9` should be indented below the `0` of `20`, and `6` should be under `0` of `10`.

Comment: Have you heard of numpy? Convert your list of lists into a 2D numpy array and then I believe even the default print is prettier.

Comment: Not yet, I'm just starting with python. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input (list of lists) `ll`:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join('%2d' % x for x in l) for l in ll)
```

Result:

```
15 16 18 19 12 11
13 19 23 21 16 12
12 15 17 19 20 10
10 14 16 13  9  6
```

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the help.

Comment: If I want to indent 2 spaces in front of each line how can I do that

Comment: `'\n'.join('  ' + ' '.join('%2d' % x for x in l) for l in ll)` this ok?